# how would you describe the act of punching someone

Tags: american-english

I need help with describing the act of punching someone, Context:

> "a VERY severe beating" just at that moment her mother [punching description] in the face knocking her out.

I remember I read in a book that went a little something like this, I have no idea what book it was

> Her arm reared back and...

Can someone help me with filling in that space?

Comment: Did you consult a thesaurus for synonyms of *punch*? If that didn’t work, then you need to explain what’s wrong with the suggestions given there.

Comment: "Punching her"... works just fine. You will need to share more details about exactly what you want the phrase to  evoke, if you want more than that simple description.

Comment: Also welcome to English Language & Usage Stack Exchange!

Comment: Her mother whacked whose face??

Comment: You need to provide more context.  What you have presented makes no sense.

Comment: @HotLicks Her daughter

Comment: Still needs context.  " 'a VERY severe beating' just at that moment her mother whacked her in the face knocking her out." -- that isn't even good syntax.

Answer (score -1):

I found out a way to do it thank you for your efforts.
Answer:

> "a VERY severe beating" just at that moment her mother reared back her arm and struck her in the face, knocking her out.

Comment: As I said, that's not good syntax.

Comment: "Reared back her arm" sounds odd; "drew back her arm" would be fine. Also, a single punch, even one that knocks somebody out, isn't a "beating".